# R: using lpSolve to solve a system of equations with constraints

Tags: r, linear-algebra, linear-programming, lpsolve

I'm trying to solve the following system of equations:

```
0.5 * x1 + 0.75 * x2 + 0.25 * x3 = 0.25
x1 + x2 + x3 = 1
```

I first randomly select $x3$ from a uniform distribution. Then I update my system of equations to solve for the remaining x1 and x2. I want to make sure that both x1 and x2 are between 0 and 1. Therefore, I set up the following system of equations to feed into `lp` from `lpSolve`. Note that I need to simultaneously maximize and minimize the objective function. But I am not sure how to do that with `lp`.

```
########
# max x1 + x2 subject to the following constraints (I want to minimize this simultaneously, but not sure how to specify this in `lp`)
# 0.5*x1 + 0.75*x2 = 1 - 0.25*x3
# x1 + x2 = 1 - x3
# x1 + 0 * x2 > 0
# 0*x1 + x2 > 0
# x1 + 0 * x2 < 1
# 0*x1 + x2 < 1

libary(lpSolve)
set.seed(3)
x3 <- runif(1, 0.01, 0.99)
f.obj <- c(1, 1)
f.con <- matrix(c(2/4, 3/4, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 6, byrow = TRUE)
f.dir <- c("=", "=", ">", ">", "<", "<")
f.rhs <- c(0.25 - 1/4 * x3, 1 - x3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
lp ("min", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs)$solution
```

Comment: Conditional on the value of `x3`, the system of linear equations has a unique solution for `x1` and `x2`, how would their sum still be maximized/minimized?

Comment: The unique solution for `x1` and `x2` may not be constrained between 0 and 1. So I set up  additional 4 constraints `x1 + 0 * x2 > 0, 0*x1 + x2 > 0, x1 + 0 * x2 < 1, 0*x1 + x2 < 1`. I tried using `matlib`'s `Solve` function, but they do not let me specify constraints that use the operators `<` or `>`. Only `=` is allowed. That's why I'm using `lp` from `lpSolve` instead.

Comment: Here is my code for using `matlib`'s `Solve`. Note that the solutions are not between 0 and 1. `library(matlib);
set.seed(3);
x3 <- runif(1, 0.01, 0.99);
A <- matrix(c(1, 2/4, 1, 3/4), 2, 2);
b <- c(1 - x3, 0.25 - 1/4 * x3);
Solve(A, b);
#x1    =  -0.34936139 
#x2  =    1.1746807`

Comment: If you would insert other values for `x1` and `x2`, the `=` equations in your linear system are no longer satisfied, because the solution you obtain is the *unique* solution for `x1` and `x2` given the linear system.